# Unable to hide element with html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

I need to hide or to make some field completely hidden in  some field in the item class. i have tried using jquery, javascript and html but the result is not too good.

```
<div class="item">
        <label for="id_mobile_number">Mobile number:</label>: <input type="text" name="mobile_number" 
       maxlength="12" required id="id_mobile_number">
</div>
                
    <div class="item">
         <label for="id_ported_number">Ported number:</label>: <input type="text" name="ported_number" 
          value="true" maxlength="100" id="id_ported_number">
    </div>
            

<div class="item">
          <label for="id_idplan">Idplan:</label>: <select name="idplan" required id="id_idplan">
           <option value="" selected>---------</option>
           <option value="1">500 at 150 for 1month</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="item">
          <label for="id_user">User:</label>: 
          <select name="user" id="id_user">
           <option value="">---------</option>
           <option value="2">akpsr@gmail.com</option>
           <option value="3">abi@gmail.com</option>
          </select>
</div>    






Am trying to make some fields invisible or completely hidden with html but the result only hide only the input field or text property while the name of the html element still shows on the form.
I want those field or element mark hidden to be completely hidden or completely invisible.
users should not be able to know that there was supposed to be an item there.
```

check my code

```
i tried using javascript and only the input field is hidden while the form name and size and other still display
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var net = document.getElementById('id_idnetwork');
       net.style.display = 'hidden';
    
    
    
    </script>
```

I tried using html but only the input is hidden while the name and other property shows
am using html id to get this field.

```
#id_user {
        position: absolute;
        display: none

      }
      #id_idplan {

        position: absolute;
        display: none
      }
```

Comment: to hide an element using `display` property the value must be `none` and not `hidden` as in your code.

Comment: @vanowm display none hide the form but the name is sill visible

Comment: There is no form tag on your listing. There is no element with id = `id_idnetwork` in your listing. When are they to be hidden? If they are never to be seen, just delete them from the markup. Otherwise, what triggers their removal? Please edit to make clear what you are trying to do preferably with actual element names and ids rather than things like 'form' which have no obvious relevance to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide siblings:

```css
[for="id_user"],
[for="id_user"] ~ * /* hide siblings */
{
  position: absolute;
  display: none

}
[for="id_idplan"],
[for="id_idplan"] ~ * /* hide siblings */
{

  position: absolute;
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
        <label for="id_mobile_number">Mobile number:</label>: <input type="text" name="mobile_number" 
       maxlength="12" required id="id_mobile_number">
</div>
                
<div class="item">
     <label for="id_ported_number">Ported number:</label> <input type="text" name="ported_number" 
      value="true" maxlength="100" id="id_ported_number">
</div>
            

<div class="item">
          <label for="id_idplan">Idplan:</label> <select name="idplan" required id="id_idplan">
           <option value="" selected>---------</option>
           <option value="1">500 at 150 for 1month</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="item">
          <label for="id_user">User:</label> 
          <select name="user" id="id_user">
           <option value="">---------</option>
           <option value="2">akpsr@gmail.com</option>
           <option value="3">abi@gmail.com</option>
          </select>
</div>
```

Or much better way is to add additional classes to the `.item` elements, so you can control it instead:

```css
.item4 {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;

}
.item3 {

  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="item item1">
        <label for="id_mobile_number">Mobile number:</label>: <input type="text" name="mobile_number" 
       maxlength="12" required id="id_mobile_number">
</div>
                
<div class="item item2">
     <label for="id_ported_number">Ported number:</label>: <input type="text" name="ported_number" 
      value="true" maxlength="100" id="id_ported_number">
</div>
            

<div class="item item3">
          <label for="id_idplan">Idplan:</label>: <select name="idplan" required id="id_idplan">
           <option value="" selected>---------</option>
           <option value="1">500 at 150 for 1month</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="item item4">
          <label for="id_user">User:</label>: 
          <select name="user" id="id_user">
           <option value="">---------</option>
           <option value="2">akpsr@gmail.com</option>
           <option value="3">abi@gmail.com</option>
          </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this??

```css
#id_user {
        position: absolute;
        display: none
      }
      
      
 #id_idplan {
        position: absolute;
        display: none
}

label#hide_user {display:none;}

select#hide_user {display:none;}
```

```html
<div class="item">
        <label for="id_mobile_number">Mobile number::</label> <input type="text" name="mobile_number" 
       maxlength="12" required id="id_mobile_number">
</div>
                
    <div class="item">
         <label for="id_ported_number">Ported number::</label> <input type="text" name="ported_number" 
          value="true" maxlength="100" id="id_ported_number">
    </div>
            

<div class="item">
          <label id="hide_user" for="id_idplan">Idplan::</label> <select id="hide_user" name="idplan" required id="id_idplan">
           <option value="" selected>---------</option>
           <option value="1">500 at 150 for 1month</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="item">
          <label id="hide_user" for="id_user">User:: </label>
          <select name="user" id="id_user">
           <option value="">---------</option>
           <option value="2">akpsr@gmail.com</option>
           <option value="3">abi@gmail.com</option>
          </select>
</div>
```

Comment: ID attribute should be [unique](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#global-attributes:html-elements-5)

Comment: @vanowm thanks so much i almost got it but unfortunately the field was not completely removed and this cascading style appeared : at the beggining of the element removed from the form. maybe am not formatting the css you gave me above well

Comment: you have `:` between HTML elements, you can't hide them without hiding the element they are in (whole `.item`)

Comment: thanks much sir- issue resolved by your answer below

Answer (score 0):

Since the release of [HTML5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/) one can now simply do:

```html
<div hidden>This div is hidden</div>
```

Note: This is not [supported](https://caniuse.com/hidden) by some old browsers, most notably IE < 11.

Hidden Attribute Documentation ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden),[W3C](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#the-hidden-attribute))

Comment: how do i use this  with the example i gave above

Comment: i want to use this attribute in css

Comment: You can use jQuery attr() Method. You can find the reference from this source: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp

Comment: i could'nt find anything related to this there - i will be grateful if u can help me out @Sahaj

Comment: No need for any jQuery, `element.setAttribute("hidden", "")` does the job.

Comment: @DavePritlove can you show me clearer sir use my example above please

Comment: No, I can't show you because you still haven't explained what you are trying to hide and when. There is no form, there is no id of id_idnetwork. Take your time and write a clear question. Doing so will probably help you see where the error is and if not, you will get a clear answer here quickly.

Comment: @EchiyeForcde Did you solved it?

Comment: @SahajRajMalla  yes boss I solved it thanks so much sir